# Zip function in Python truncating floating digits

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

I am using Python's regular expression to grab few values from a typical scientific simulation log file. A shortened version of this log file is shown below:

```
Time = 500

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.000185956, Final residual = 8.56685e-06, No Iterations 4
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.00338876, Final residual = 0.00016085, No Iterations 4
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.00412929, Final residual = 0.000195655, No Iterations 4
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0135009, Final residual = 0.000416508, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 8.12599e-05, global = -2.7703e-06, cumulative = -0.0058176
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 6.29185e-05, Final residual = 4.26272e-06, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.000658395, Final residual = 4.89427e-05, No Iterations 3
ExecutionTime = 537.04 s  ClockTime = 537 s
```

My code is:

```
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    for line in logfile_read:
        line = line.rstrip()

        if 'Time' in line:
            iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)

        if ('local' or 'global' or 'cumulative') in line:
            local_global_cumu = re.search(r'sum\s+local\s+=\s+(.*),\s+global\s+=\s+(.*),\s+cumulative\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
            if local_global_cumu:
                contLocal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(1)
                contGlobal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(2)
                contCumulative_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(3)

            contLocal_0_time_value = zip(iteration_time,contLocal_0_value)
            print contLocal_0_value
            print contLocal_0_time_value
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
8.12599e-05
[('500', '8')]
```

After `zip()`, the value `8.12599e-05` is truncated to `8`

Why is this happening with `zip()` and how to solve this issue? I cannot use `float()` within `zip()`.

Answer (score 1):

From `zip`'s doc:

`The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.`

You're zipping the list `['500']` with the string `'8.12599e-05'`, so the result is `[('500', '8')]`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you probably meant

```
zip(iteration_time, [contLocal_0_value])
```

?

Comment: As you can see in my code, I have two lists `iteration_time` and `contLocal_0_value` and I need to combine in such a way that I need to get `500 <space> 8.12599e-05'. This is because, the time `500` corresponds to the value `8.12599e-05`. Thanks @Rawing

Comment: `contLocal_0_value` is not a list, it's a string. How exactly do you want to combine the two?

Comment: Basically, my log file is very long and for each time iteration, I get a set of data as shown above and I am extracting values from it. I want to combine in such a way I get `500   8.12599e-05` and I will be writing this to a text file so that it can be plotted. Thanks @Rawing

Comment: Okay, assuming you just want the _first_ element in the list, just do `print '%s %s'%(iteration_time[0], contLocal_0_value)`. If you want _all_ elements in the list, you can do something like `print ['%s %s'%(t, contLocal_0_value) for t in iteration_time]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `contLocal_0_value` is a string not a list so you need to use `zip(iteration_time, [contLocal_0_value])`.

```
import re

with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    for line in logfile_read:
        line = line.rstrip()

        if 'Time' in line:
            iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)

        if ('local' or 'global' or 'cumulative') in line:
            local_global_cumu = re.search(
                (r'sum\s+local\s+=\s+(.*),\s+global\s+=\s+(.*),'
                    r'\s+cumulative\s+=\s+(.*)'),
                line)
            if local_global_cumu:
                contLocal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(1)
                contGlobal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(2)
                contCumulative_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(3)

            contLocal_0_time_value = zip(iteration_time, [contLocal_0_value])
            print contLocal_0_value
            print contLocal_0_time_value
```

Output:

```
8.12599e-05
[('500', '8.12599e-05')]
```